# Can't validate input because of name

Tags: jquery, validation, struts2

I need to validate input when the `currentTarjeta.causaDeUnicoServicioContratado` `CheckBox` is checked. The problem is that I need this odd name `currentTarjeta.causaDeUnicoServicioContratado`. If I use `something` as the name this works. How do I fix this?

```
"currentTarjeta.causaDeUnicoServicioContratado": {
    required: "#currentTarjeta.causaDeUnicoServicioContratado:checked",
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the dot using "\\"

Example:

```
 // Instead of
 $("#something.id")

 // Write
 $("#something\\.id")
```

It will work :)

Comment: the reason you need 2 backslashes is that the first one is interpreted by Javascript, and the next one is interpreted by JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly the problem. The dot assumes a css class name. How about using an underscore or a dash instead of a dot in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Well i kinda find a solution.

I use named my tag `name="man.name"` and y use de id attribute `id=name`.

So when i use the validate function i call de id and not the name:

```
required: "#name:checked"
```

and this works :)